# Strange behavior in reading xml from isolated storage

Tags: xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, isolatedstorage

In my app I am reading a XML stored in isolated storage. XML is as following

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Root>
      <Fact>
        <imageName>tumblr_inline_mp8rloanHl1qz4rgp.jpg</imageName>
        <ImageURL>http://mline_mp8rloanHl1qz4rgp.jpg</ImageURL>
        <imageTime>Mon, 01 Jul 2013 10:42:59 +0530</imageTime>

        <imageRef>http://media.tumblr/5bae62d98c52c367/tumblrgp.jpg</imageRef>
        <imageCopied>No</imageCopied>
      </Fact>
  <Fact>
    <imageName>tumblr_mp8dtoGGFs1qkvbwso1_500.png</imageName>
    <ImageURL>http://25.media./tumblr_mp8dtoGGFs1qkvbwso1_500.png</ImageURL>
    <imageTime>Mon, 01 Jul 2013 08:28:00 +0530</imageTime>

    <imageRef>http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moondyne_Joe</imageRef>
    <imageCopied>No</imageCopied>
  </Fact>
    </Root>
```

I want to read the first `<imageName>` in first `<Fact>`. Here is my code

```
XDocument readedDoc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                var root = readedDoc.Element("Fact");
```

But root is always null. However if I do replace "Fact" with "Root", var root contains first node in xml.

```
XDocument readedDoc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
                var root = readedDoc.Element("Root");
```

Kindly tell me about the error and if possible provide me with the code to read the specific "imageName" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Element` will only search the immediate children. So if you want to use this method, you have first to retrieve root, and then Fact:

```
XDocument readedDoc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
var root = readedDoc.Element("Root");
var fact = root.Element("Fact");
```

Or you can use `Descendants` instead to browse the whole tree:

```
XDocument readedDoc = XDocument.Load(isoStream);
var fact = readedDoc.Descendants("Fact").First();
```